# What is the image of the function $ g(A)= A\begin{matrix}(222)^t\end{matrix} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

g: V-> R2 and V is a vector space of 2x3 real matrices. I know that the definition of the image is {f(v)=w , w belongs to W(range)} but I am unsure of how to apply this to specific examples.

Comment: Your definition of the image is nonsense as written.  Presumably, you means something like
$$
\{f(v) \mid v \in V\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You know the image lies in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
To show the image is actually all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, just consider matrices $A$ such that two columns are zero. then $A \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}$ will just be two times the nonzero column.

Comment: $ \begin{bmatrix} 
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix}
\quad $ Would this be a right matrix for A ?